# In Visual Basic, how can you input something in the same line?

Tags: vb.net, user-input, console-input

Sorry if my question isn't that clear. We usually write it like:

```
dim num as integer
Console.writeline("Input num")
num = console.readline()
```

How can you write that `input num` and the value on `num` on the same line, what I wrote will do it on two different lines...

Answer (score 1):

Using `Write` will prevent adding a trailing newline.

```
Console.Write("Input num: ")
Dim num = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be console.writeline instead of Console.writeline? 
  
And what does that Integer.Parse thing mean?

Comment: @VojtechVrbka: "Link-only" on an answer that has no link. Yeah, no.